# javascript - Get value using a function return

Tags: javascript, jquery, return

I am trying to write a simple function to avoid replication of code and return a value from an input but when I try to return it via the function i just get "undefined".

Any ideas why?

```
function get_selected_id() {
    return $(this).parents("tr").find("input[name*=page_id]").val();
}

$("a").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(get_selected_id()); // RETURNS UNDEFINED
    alert($(this).parents("tr").find("input[name*=page_id]").val()); // RETURNS 123
});
```

html (very simplified):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>page id <input type="hidden" value="123" name="page_id[]" /></td>
        <td><a href="#">Click</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't pass the value to `get_selected_id()`. So when the function tries to return `$(this)` it is undefined because it can't match any element. You have to pass as argument the element that is clicked!

Try

```
function get_selected_id(e) {
    return e.parents("tr").find("input[name*=page_id]").val();
}

$("a").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(get_selected_id($(this))); // RETURNS 123
    alert($(this).parents("tr").find("input[name*=page_id]").val()); // RETURNS 123
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f5Pr6/)

Answer (score 0):

**this** keyword in javascript is context-dependent.

Try to pass $(this) as argument to your function:

```
function get_selected_id(obj) {
    return obj.parents("tr").find("input[name*=page_id]").val();
}

alert(get_selected_id($(this)));
```